# Get the selected value of a list of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of radio buttons each with the same `name` attribute. The following JavaScript is meant to detect a change in any of the buttons and pass the selected value to the `getColumnNames()` method.

```
$("input[name=SelectedSheet]:radio").change(function () {
    getColumnNames(this.val());
})
```

It detects when any of the buttons change, but it doesn't pass the string value of the selected radio button.

In Firebug, when one of the radio buttons is clicked, the `this` keyword contains the following:

```
input#SelectedSheet_Second Sheet attribute value = "Second Sheet"
```

Btw, `SelectedSheet` is the `name` attribute of the list of radio buttons.

How do I pass the value of the selected attribute to the `getColumnNames()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.val()` is a jQuery method, so you must wrap `this` with `$()` to use it:

```
getColumnNames($(this).val());
```

Or you can just use plain JS:

```
getColumnNames(this.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the :radio, since it will find it by the name. Then use $(this).val() instead

```
<input type="radio" name="SelectedSheet" value="sheet1" />
<input type="radio" name="SelectedSheet" value="sheet2" />
<input type="radio" name="SelectedSheet" value="sheet3" />

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[name="SelectedSheet"]').change(function () {
      alert($(this).val());
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fxsupvhj/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$(this).val();` inside your code.

```
$("input[name=SelectedSheet]:radio").change(function () {
    getColumnNames($(this).val());
})
```